# How can I add my license to the top of files autogenerated by openapi-generator?

Tags: go, openapi-generator

I want to customize [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/faq-extending/) to auto generate code with a specific license header at the top of every file.

I figured I need to edit [openapi-generator/src/main/resources/go/partial_header.mustache](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/go/partial_header.mustache), is it a good idea just to paste a bunch of license text on top of that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their documentation, it depends on what the current generator provides, but in general, you will need to modify the templates and as such, maintain a custom template directory.

The only restriction you would face with adding the license content to the top of the `partial_header.mustache` template file you referenced, is that it should not contain any content that may be interpretable by the `jmustache` template engine.

Since the license text also does not involve actual code, there should be no issues with simply adding it to the template file, or even replacing the existing content in the template file.

It also seems as though you may not need to maintain an entire copy of the template structure, and only the template files you need, by using the external configuration files section during generation ([According to this documentation](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization/)).

Answer (score 0):

This link: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization/ provides the basic information, but it does not address specific cases.
For example, if you are using the openapi maven plugin, it does not specify how you can configure it. The point is to add a configurationFile option, as listed below:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <templateDirectory>src/main/api-spring-templates</templateDirectory>
            <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/api/services/broker-service.yaml</inputSpec>
            <artifactId>broker-api</artifactId>
            <configurationFile>src/main/api-spring-templates/conf.yaml</configurationFile>
            ....
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

In this configuration file you can specify any additional files that you would require. For example:

```
files:
   License.mustache:
   templateType: SupportingFiles
   destinationFilename: License.md
```

Plus, of course, creating the associated License.mustache file (or directly a License.md file, if no templating is required). This file should be available in your template folder, as specified in the templateDirectory configuration parameter.